# Is Madaline neural network and ther train almost the same as a multilayer perceptron(MLP)? what's the difference?

Tags: neural-networks

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adaline-and-madaline-network/

Is the Madaline neural network and its training mode almost the same or identical to a multilayer perceptron (MLP)? what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

[Madaline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADALINE#MADALINE) is a three-layer (input, hidden, output), fully connected, feed-forward artificial neural network architecture for classification but not regression tasks.

> Three different training algorithms for MADALINE networks, which cannot be learned using backpropagation because the sign function is not differentiable, have been suggested, called Rule I, Rule II and Rule III.

> MADALINE Rule 3 - The third "Rule" applied to a modified network with sigmoid activations instead of signum; it was later found to be equivalent to backpropagation.